# how to avoid error after refreshing the page in php

Tags: php

actually this is regarding a simple query in php i have a simple html login form as follow with post method and login table in the database with fields username password ...etc i am able to get the desire result but when i get the result i refresh that page and an error come

```
Notice: Undefined index: usrname in C:\xampp\htdocs\tut\pro\ex1.php on line 9

Notice: Undefined index: password in C:\xampp\htdocs\tut\pro\ex1.php on line 10
```

.........what i want  to know is how can i avoid this error after refreshing the page is there any method to do so.

```
 <html><body>
<form method="post" action="ex1.php">
username:<input type="text" name="usrname" value=""><br>
passsword:<input type="password" name = "password" value=""><br>
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="sign up">
</form>
</html>
</body>
```

ex1.php is as follow :

```
 <?php
$cxn= mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","movie");
if(mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo" error connecting ".mysqli_connect_error();
}

if (isset($_POST)) {
$username=$_POST['usrname'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$sql="select * from login where username= '$username' and password= '$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
unset($_POST);


if($result)
{
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == '1')
{
echo "<h1>welcome &nbsp".$username."&nbsp on your account</h1>";
}}}
?>
```

Comment: IF you refresh your page, you should get browser question if you want do send data one more time, and when you accept it, you should get the same result without any warnings.

Comment: im working it on local host there m getting error...and how to add browser question can u help plz

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this,

```
username:<input type="text" name="usrname"><br>
passsword:<input type="password" name = "password"><br>

$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$sql="select * from login where username= '$username' and password= '$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
```

to this..

```
username:<input type="text" name="usrname" value=""><br>
passsword:<input type="password" name = "password" value=""><br>

if (isset($_POST)) {
$username=$_POST['username'];
$password=$_POST['password'];
$sql="select * from login where username= '$username' and password= '$password'";
$result=mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
unset($_POST);
}
```

Then your variables will only be created when the user submits the form.

Comment: no there is no prob in this as u can c in my code tht name is usrname but variable is $username....so i think no prob over here

Comment: Yes I saw that. I see the problem, you are not sending a value with your form, see my update.

Comment: actually m not getting any error on submitting its working fine but when i get the right result then i refresh the page on which in got the result ....as we know $_POST will take the value which we entered in username and password but after the value when we refresh how to hold that value without any error

Comment: The error is occurring in ex1.php, not in sqllogacc1.php. The problem is elsewhere from what you have provided.

Comment: i just changed the name of the page see now